# python2.7 package unmet dependency problem on Ubuntu

Tags: python, debconf

I am really new to ubuntu OS and I unknowingly may have modified some packages and ended up in python2.7-minimal, python-2.7-stdlib, python2.7-stdlibrary dependency problem.

I tried to recover it using

`sudo apt-get -f install` I got the below output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb dmeventd dmraid dpkg-repack gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0 kpartx kpartx-boot libappstream3 libdebian-installer4
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 liblockfile-bin liblockfile1
  liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 libparted-fs-resize0 libreadline5
  lockfile-progs lvm2 os-prober pmount python3-icu python3-pam rdate
  ubiquity-casper ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  add-apt-key apt apt-utils aptdaemon libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libqt4-designer libqt4-help
  libqt4-opengl libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt4-test
  libqtassistantclient4 libqtwebkit4 python-apt python-bs4 python-chardet
  python-html5lib python-lxml python-mechanize python-pkg-resources python-qt4
  python-sip python-six python2.7-minimal python3-aptdaemon
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
Suggested packages:
  aptitude | synaptic | wajig apt-doc python-apt-dbg python-apt-doc
  python-genshi python-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc python-setuptools
  python-qt4-dbg binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  add-apt-key libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-opengl libqt4-scripttools
  libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libqtwebkit4 python-apt
  python-bs4 python-chardet python-html5lib python-lxml python-mechanize
  python-pkg-resources python-qt4 python-sip python-six
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils aptdaemon libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib python2.7-minimal python3-aptdaemon
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
11 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 675 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 69.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to reinstall python2.7 and whatever command I try upgrade and all I am getting is the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

This the output of apt cache policy:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.11-1
  Candidate: 2.7.12-1~16.04
  Version table:
     2.7.12-1~16.04 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
     2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**sudo apt autoremove**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is installed
python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is installed
Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is installed

**sudo apt update**
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
686 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

**sudo apt upgrade**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is installed
python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is installed
Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13) but 2.7.11-7ubuntu1 is installed

I am really new to this. Please help

Comment: Check your sources, a quick scan (`rmadison` shows packages available in -security & -updates, but you may not have them enabled.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  Why did you provide the `apt-cache policy` for a different package to the one your install error message applies to?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am a beginner in this I don't know how to make both the versions same. Can you please tell me what do i do to make them same

Comment: before installing any new software you should always first update the list of software (`sudo apt update`) and install updates for existing packages (`sudo apt upgrade`) - otherwise you can get this kind of mess.  Please run `sudo apt autoremove` as suggested in the first error, then try to `update` and `upgrade`.  Please add the output of each of those commands if you are still getting errors with your package management system.  This is a "Red Light: Do Not Continue" if you are getting errors with `apt update` and `apt upgrade`

Comment: I tried with the commands and i get the same unmet dependencies issue

Comment: Looks like you installed Xenial (16.04), a 4.5-year-old release that will lose support soon. Consider a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal). If you decive to keep Xenial, then what were you trying to accomplish by mucking with your Python install?

Comment: I am working on nvidia tx2 gpu.To my knowledge it may not support 20.04 version.